# Laravel: Make Images Stored in Storage Folder Publicly Accessible

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-filesystem

I am storing images in the Laravel storage folder. They are stored in the following format.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\personal_projects\Active\diary_app\storage\app\images\C4CA4238\C81E728D9D4C2F63.png

I want to make these images publicly accessible for the user that uploaded them. I followed the instructions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

> *"you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to"*
>   storage/app/public

So I ran `php artisan storage:link` and have the "symbolic link" showing up in my public directory:

[image]

I am trying to display my images using the following url:

> http://localhost/personal_projects/Active/diary_app/public/storage/app/images/C4CA4238/C81E728D9D4C2F63.png"

But I get 'image not found'. How do I make images stored in storage publicly accessible?

Comment: Okay, trying both suggestions now. Thanks you.

Comment: no, i deleted my comment because he's not using any conf, just going frol localhost/ @BenCarey

Comment: I tried removing `public` and it works, but won't work on a server because the images won't be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images stored in the `storage/app/public` directory are publicly accessible via `http://your.domain/storage` when the `php artisan storage:link` command has been run.

I.e, `storage_path('app/public') . '/path/to/image.jpg'` would be accessed like so: `http://your.domain/storage/path/to/image.jpg`.